# Is there an equivalent to C# 6's using static clause in TypeScript?

Tags: c#, typescript

**Is there an equivalent to C# 6's using static clause in TypeScript?**

How it works in C# 6:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx#Anchor_0

```
using static System.Console; 
using static System.Math;
class Program 
{ 
    static void Main() 
    { 
        WriteLine(Sqrt(3*3 + 4*4)); 
    } 
}
```

**Why?**
Same motivation for it's use in c#, cut down on code clutter when using module namespaces.

I've tried the following:

```
let f = My.Namespace;
var f1 = My.Namespace;
```

The assignment succeeds, but I am unable to use these variables like a namespace.

```
var a: f.SomethingInNamespace
```

gives the error

```
Cannot find namespace 'f'.
```

Although intellisense in VS 2015 finds the members.

Comment: Moving *types* around and moving *variables* around are different things and the topic is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `import` keyword:

```
import f = My.Namespace;
```

Comment: I've been trying that , but I keep getting ref errors.                                 import m = Microsoft.Maps;  var msMap = new m.Map(...);                                           i then get this : tstBing.ts:1Uncaught ReferenceError: Microsoft is not defined.  however if I reference the full namespace it works fine, so the reference error is unclear to me. using td.s from bing maps 7